# Jquery get url value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, path

Today, I come to ask for your help on a small javascript problem.
how can url work with this jquery

example url

> http://mywebsite.com/?link=f9891188&title=My_Post_Title&dLink1=http://url.com/one&dLink2=http://url.com/two&dLink3=http://url.com/three&dLink4=http://url.com/four&gplay=1234

this html and javascript

```js
function GetUrlValue(a) {
 var b = window.location.search.substring(1);
 var c = b.split('&');
 for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  var d = c[i].split('=');
  if (d[0] == a) {
   return d[1]
  }
 }
}
$('#title').html('<h2>' + GetUrlValue('title') + '</h2>');
if (geoip_country_code() == 'TK' || geoip_country_name() == 'Tokelau') {}
else {
 if (GetUrlValue('dLink1') == '') {
  $('#url1').html('No link')
 } else {
  $('#url1').attr('onclick', "this.href='" + GetUrlValue('dLink1') + "'")
 }
 if (GetUrlValue('dLink2') == '') {
  $('#url2').html('No link')
 } else {
  $('#url2').attr('onclick', "this.href='" + GetUrlValue('dLink2') + "'")
 }
 if (GetUrlValue('dLink3') == '') {
  $('#url3').html('No link')
 } else {
  $('#url3').attr('onclick', "this.href='" + GetUrlValue('dLink3') + "'")
 }
 if (GetUrlValue('dLink4') == '') {
  $('#url4').html('No link')
 } else {
  $('#url4').attr('onclick', "this.href='" + GetUrlValue('dLink4') + "'")
 }
 $('#gp').attr('onclick', "this.href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + GetUrlValue('gplay') + "'");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
 document.title = ('' + GetUrlValue('title') + '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/country.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>

<section>
<div id='container_buttons'>
<p>
<a class='a_btn 1' href='#' id='url1' onclick='' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Download'>Download 1</a>
</p>
<p>
<a class='a_btn 2' href='#' id='url2' onclick='' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Download'>Download 2</a>
</p>
<p>
<a class='a_btn 3' href='#' id='url3' onclick='' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Download'>Download 3</a>
</p>
<p>
<a class='a_btn 4' href='#' id='url4' onclick='' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Download'>Download 4</a>
</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you elaborate on what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit at what you want, but if you are trying to read values out of the query string and set the anchor tags `href` attribute accordingly, you could proceed as follows.

Here is a good function to extract values from a query string:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Ref: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

With the rest, you could DRY up your `if/else` statements a little by selecting any `a` elements whose `id` begin with url, then setting the `href` accordingly:

```
$("a[id^='url']").each(function(){
  var linkParam = "dLink" + this.id.replace("url", "");

  if (getParameterByName(linkParam)) {
    this.href= getParameterByName(linkParam);
  } else {
    $(this).text('No link')
  }
});
```

For the following query string (notice dLink4 is missing):

```
http://example.com/?link=f9891188&title=My_Post_Title&dLink1=http://url.com/one&dLink2=http://url.com/two&dLink3=http://url.com/three
```

You get the following markup:

```
<section>
  <div id="container_buttons">
    <p>
      <a class="a_btn 1" href="http://url.com/one" id="url1">Download 1</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="a_btn 2" href="http://url.com/two" id="url2">Download 2</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="a_btn 3" href="http://url.com/three" id="url3">Download 3</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="a_btn 4" href="#" id="url4">No link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```